# Progress Bar for Directory copy(including subdirectories)

Tags: vb.net

I think im stuck with a wrong approach to a problem. Im trying to get a reliable progress bar for copying files to an USB-Drive. My Problem is that with my approach, it will work but not reliable show the necessary information, as the file created event will trigger way before the file has completed to write ( and in case of directory copy, its multithreated and will create almost all files immediately but will write for far far longer especially if the usb dirve is slow (usb 2.0). Below is my approach, but I'm sure there must be a better way to solve this problem.

```
Public counterLocalFiles As String
Private Sub CopyUSB
        fsw_USB = New IO.FileSystemWatcher(Path)
        fsw_USB.IncludeSubdirectories = True
        fsw_USB.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        UpdateProgressBarMaximum2(CInt(counterLocalFiles))
        counterLocalFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, 
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(SourcePath, Path)"*.jpg*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length    
End Sub

Private Sub fsw_USB_Created(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs) Handles fsw_USB.Created
        Dim counterUSBFiles = IO.Directory.GetFiles(Path, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length
        UpdateProgressBar2(CInt(counterUSBFiles))
        UpdateLabelText2(CStr(counterUSBFiles) & " von " & CStr(counterLocalFiles))
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateProgressBarMaximum2(Maximum As Int32)
    If ProgressBar2.InvokeRequired Then
        ProgressBar2.Invoke(New Action(Of Integer)(AddressOf UpdateProgressBarMaximum2), Maximum)
    Else
        'We are on the UI thread so update the control.
        ProgressBar2.Maximum = Maximum
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateProgressBar2(Value As Int32)
    If ProgressBar2.InvokeRequired Then
        ProgressBar2.Invoke(New Action(Of Integer)(AddressOf UpdateProgressBar2), Value)
    Else
        'We are on the UI thread so update the control.
        ProgressBar2.Value = Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You know there is a UI option for the CopyDirectory process? `FileSystem.CopyDirectory(sourcePath, destinationPath,
            UIOption.AllDialogs)` using `UIOption.AllDialogs` will show the windows copy progress dialog.

Comment: actually i didnt know that, i kinda would want to implent it in the ui though. since i do multiple file copies at once ( 2-3 with backgroundworkers) so it would be easier to see all file copies at once. But thanks for that quick workarrouind i suppose :)

Comment: If you want more control and a more accurate copy process, there is a way to do it without a `FileSystemWatcher`, but it's more complicated. Instead of doing `CopyDirectory`, you copy of each file individually creating directories as you go. To be even more accurate, you can get a listing of everything that needs copied including filesize, use a `FileStream` to read/write bytes of each file being copied and update your progress. I've done it with a background worker to update the UI.

Comment: I'm really new to VB and to programming in generall. But im trying to ask as much as possible (--> learn as much as possible). Wha you suggested sounds really great for my problem, but i dont quite get on how to use the Filestream if I look at the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example of how to do it using a `BackgroundWorker` and `FileStream`. The code is more than I can post here...because it's a Visual Studio project...so I've zipped it up and you can download it here: http://www.filedropper.com/copydirectoryvisualstudioexample

You can run it and select Source and Destination folders.

The main directory copy process happens in `bgwDirectoryCopy_DoWork` and the individual file copy process happens in `copyFileWithProgress`

Just modify however you need...right now it copies `*.*`

Comment: btw, is FileStream jusst as reliable as Filesystem.CopyDirectory is? will it throw just as Filecopy would if something goes wrong?

Comment: yes, just catch any exception that's thrown as it's copying the file and handle it however you need